# Unable to search jsonb field in postgres

Tags: postgresql

I have a jsonb field named payment in postgres version 10 with value :

`[{"bank": "SBI", "amount": "100", "ref_no": "123", "payment_mode": "1"}]`.

When I tried to search `payment->'payment_mode'='1'`.
It shows empty rows.

Following is the query

```
SELECT * FROM bill WHERE payment->>'payment_mode'='1'
```

But when trying this query it shows the exact result

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    json_array_elements(
        '[{"bank": "SBI", "amount": "100", "ref_no": "123", "payment_mode": "1"}]'
    ) AS elem
WHERE
    elem->>'payment_mode' = '1';
```

Is any solution available  to search the values in jsonb field to get the result as

```
`{"bank": "SBI", "amount": "100", "ref_no": "123", "payment_mode": "1"}`.
```

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly understand, you need something like this:

```
select bill.*, e.*
from bill 
join lateral jsonb_array_elements(payment) e(v)
on true
where v->>'payment_mode'='1';
```